# Why Does OSX VoiceOver Read Figures With Figcaptions Twice in Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, accessibility, voiceover, screen-readers

The Markup

```
<figure class="question">
    <blockquote>
        <span>test text</span>
    </blockquote>
    <figcaption class="citation">Test Value</figcaption>
</figure>
```

When you run OSX voiceover in "read mode" (VO + A), it reads this as

> test text, figure;
>
> test text

It reads the `<blockquote>` value twice and never reads the `<figcaption>` value. If you remove the `<figcaption>` it reads the value once.

I've also tested this with an image wrapped in `<figure>` with a `<figcaption>` and in that case, it reads the `<figcaption>` twice.

Has anyone else ever run into this? I'm starting to think it might be a bug in Chrome itself.

Comment: This doesn't answer the "why", but did you try firefox and safari with VO?  Do they read it correctly?  How about VO on iOS with safari, chrome, and firefox?  Do you have access to a PC so you can try NVDA (free)?  I'm just curious if you're only seeing this on chrome.

Comment: I tried safari and Firefox on Mac and they both read it correctly